# Failed to looping javascript with HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I failed to looping data with javascript and show it inside HTML table, the failed is the data that shown is not right as i expected, the data is outside the table, how to make the data show inside the table

HTML code :

```
  <table style="border: 1px solid">
    <thead>
      <th>Name</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <div id="demo"></div>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Javascript code :

```
      const cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford"];

      let i = 0;
      let text = "";

      for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        text += "<tr> <td>"+ cars[i] + "</td> </tr>";
      }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

The result :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIzCA.png)

Comment: You're creating invalid HTML. Remove the `div` and give the same id to [`tbody`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody) element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All table content should be inside cells, your div is in tbody - that's why table drop it out.

In your case - remove div and set his id to `<tbody>`

```
<table style="border: 1px solid">
   <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
   </thead>
  <tbody id="demo"></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do following changes :

```
 <table style="border: 1px solid">
    <thead>
      <th>Name</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="demo"></tbody>
  </table>
```